# Should I wait for my professor to reply my request for recommendation letter?

Tags: etiquette, recommendation-letter

I am going to apply to graduate programs in the US, so I contacted my professor who advised my master's thesis. He is the most important referee because I did research with him, so I think he understands me well. Moreover, he is a well-known scientist in a very prestigious university in France (top 20 of the world in my field).

At the time, I left France to my home country, he told me that he would help me further my academic career. He actually gave me two recommendation letters afterwards for 2 PhD positions. Sadly, I failed both of them.

Ten days ago, I emailed him if he could give me recommendation letters. He didn't reply for one week, so I wrote a follow-up email. However, I haven't got any responses from him until now. I am so confused because the deadline is December 15th.

Does it mean that my professor has declined my request? Should I wait for him or ask other professors?

NEWS: I just got his acceptance. He was traveling this week so he didn't got my email. Thank you all for your advices.

Comment: Does the professor know you failed the previous PhD attempts?  Also, he could be very busy.

Comment: Also, related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/32730/65092

Comment: @Nullarbor Yes, he knew the results.

Comment: How long do you have to get the letters? If the deadline is approaching, you can use that to put a (small) bit of pressure on the professor. Also, how much does the professor need to change if (s)he starts with a previous letter as template? Would a simple change in the person to be addressed be enough or should the entire letter be rewritten?

Comment: Wait a week after the most recent reminder.  Then, if you still haven't heard back, one week before the due date, or slightly earlier, telephone his department, explain your problem, and ask the secretary to give a personal message to the professor.  Sometimes professors can get overwhelmed with work and deadlines.  Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Professors are really (really) busy. Most likely he simply did not have time yet to reply to your email. Or maybe he is at a conference and does not have access to the previous two letters on his office computer. He will probably reply to your message later.

To get his recommendation letter quickly the best thing you can do is make it as easy for him as possible. Because you already have two of his letters I suggest you write your own new recommendation letter based on these two, send it to him by email, and ask him to sign it. This is quite common, at least in the different labs in the UK and France where I have worked: many professors ask students to write their own letter, after which they may make a few changes and sign it. This saves them lots of time.

Also, make sure to let him know when your deadline is so he understands the urgency.